# Polars: Trouble with few transformations

Tags: python-polars

1. What if I want divide only a and c column in above operation? How can I do that?

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[3,3,3],'b':[6,6,9], 'c':[6,6,9]})
df = df.with_columns(pl.all()/3.0)
```

2. For below transformation, what am I doing wrong as I am getting an error:

```
    import polars as pl import pandas as pd from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

    data = { 'last_seen': [5, 20, 3, 8, 12], 'dates': [date(2023, 6, 20), date(2023, 5, 15), date(2023, 6, 27), date(2023, 6, 19), date(2023, 6, 10)] }

    df_polars = pl.DataFrame(data)

    today = date(2023, 6, 30)

    range_mask = ( (df_polars['last_seen'] >= -5) & ( (df_polars['last_seen'] < 15) | ( ( (df_polars['dates'] > today) & ((df_polars['dates'] - today).dt.days > (df_polars['last_seen'] - 15)) ) ) ) )

df_polars = df_polars.with_column(pl.when(range_mask).then(True).otherwise(False)).alias('active')
```

Comment: (1) Use fancy indexing.  `df[['a','c']] = df[['a','c']] / 3`.   (2) What error are you getting, and on which line?  And what are you expecting that to do?

Comment: Don't use "fancy indexing" with polars.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, there are a few ways to do multiple column selection, such as [`exclude`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.exclude.html#polars-exclude) or the new [`selectors`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html) module:

```py
# all of these have equivalent results on the test dataframe given
df.with_columns(pl.exclude('b') / 3.0)
df.with_columns(cs.by_name('a', 'c') / 3.0)
df.with_columns(~cs.by_name('b') / 3.0)
```

For #2, the `dt.days` call is a method, not an attribute. Also the `alias` call is for an expression and should be inside the `with_columns` (`with_column` is deprecated) call, not outside it:

```py
range_mask = ((df_polars["last_seen"] >= -5) & ((df_polars["last_seen"] < 15))) | (
    (
        (df_polars["dates"] > today)
        & ((df_polars["dates"] - today).dt.days() > (df_polars["last_seen"] - 15))
    )
)

df_polars.with_columns(pl.when(range_mask).then(True).otherwise(False).alias('active'))
```

```py
shape: (5, 3)
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────┐
│ last_seen ┆ dates      ┆ active │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---    │
│ i64       ┆ date       ┆ bool   │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪════════╡
│ 5         ┆ 2023-06-20 ┆ true   │
│ 20        ┆ 2023-05-15 ┆ false  │
│ 3         ┆ 2023-06-27 ┆ true   │
│ 8         ┆ 2023-06-19 ┆ true   │
│ 12        ┆ 2023-06-10 ┆ true   │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────┘
```

While this fixed code does work, it is not the most "Polars-esque" way to do the operation. You don't need a `when` when the `then`/`otherwise` is simply True/False - the original boolean expression can be used as is. There are also [expressions](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/index.html) to do each part of `range_mask` (such as `any`, `all`, `is_between`), you don't need to do direct column indexing like `pandas` would. Here's an example that gives the same result:

```py
df_polars.with_columns(
    active=pl.any(
        pl.col("last_seen").is_between(-5, 15, closed="left"),
        pl.all(
            pl.col("dates") > today,
            (pl.col("dates") - today).dt.days() > pl.col("last_seen") - 15,
        ),
    )
)
```

Comment: Are you sure if the last snippet is correct? last_seen >= -5 and then there are bunch of conditions? I am not sure but is_between(-5, 15) looks not right

Comment: It's a perfect translation of `range_mask` to me, unless you did not write `range_mask` correctly in the first place. `is_between` with the right `closed` argument is shorthand for > (>=) and < (<=).